# chirp and WebRTC simultaneously - no echo cancellation

Tags: javascript, webrtc, opentok, echo-cancellation, chirp

I am attempting to listen for chirps (using the webassembly 16kHz-mono 3.1.0 version)  while simultaneously communicating with a secondary device over WebRTC which is also listening for chirps.

In a situation where the two devices are connected and transmitting sound to eachother, if I instantiate a Chirp and call `chirp.start()`, there is no longer any echo cancellation, ie. echoes occur. How can I facilitate for using chirps  without having an echo between the two devices?

*To clarify, I do not want to transmit the chirp over WebRTC, and intend to filter away that part of the frequency spectrum prior to transmission.*

*Tested on Chrome 75.0 on multiple OSs using opentok.js for WebRTC.*

Comment: The Chirp WebAssembly SDK disables any audio processing by the browser when issuing the getUserMedia request. Just out of interest, is echo cancellation enabled if you start Chirp before your WebRTC library?

Comment: @joerobot Ah that explains it. Regarding your question, order does not make a difference. I presume this is because opentok does not set any constraints, while chirp does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting constraints in opentok should resolve your issue.